# Css Improve style

Tags: html, css

How can I improve these css to not repeat the background-position? Can I add something inside each of the icons to refer to another class that add the background-position?

```
.icon-add-item {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_addItem.png");
    background-position: 50%;
}

.icon-remove-item {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_removeItem.png");
    background-position: 50%;
}

.icon-dragdrop-item {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_layout1_dragDrop.png");
    background-position: 50%;
}

.icon-filter-column {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_layout1_filter.png");
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Could I see your html to give some more improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the common CSS rule for all of those classes at once, rather than defining it for each like so:

```
.icon-add-item {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_addItem.png");
}

.icon-remove-item {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_removeItem.png");
}

.icon-dragdrop-item {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_layout1_dragDrop.png");
}

.icon-filter-column {
    background-image: url("../../../images/Reports/icon_layout1_filter.png");
}

.icon-add-item, .icon-remove-item, .icon-dragdrop-item, .icon-filter-column {
    background-position: 50%;
}
```